# Increment and decrement number using loop

Tags: for-loop, vbscript, increment, decrement

I'm trying to print range of 2 numbers from 1 to 150 along with some text.
That is 1st range is in ascending order 1 to 150 and second is descending from 150 to 1. 
I can print the ascending order , but I'm not sure how to go with the descending order.

```
Set xml = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")


For i = 1 to 150

 TL1( "HELLO"&i&"INCRESING"&i&";" ) // In both the statement i should increment from 1 to 150 and  
TL1( "HELLO"&n&"INCRESING_I"&i&"DECRESING_N"&n&";" ) //  n should decrement from 150 to 1

Next

Set xml = Nothing

Function TL1( cmd ) 
xml.Open "GET", "http://127.0.0.1:2024/TL1?"&cmd, False
xml.Send
TL1 = xml.responseText
WScript.Stdout.Write cmd & vbCrLf
End Function
```

so basically after the for statement. i should increment and n should decrement. Is there a way I can add this n in the same forloop ?

Comment: Instead of just using i, use 150 - i in the second TL1()

Comment: @RobertAltman, actually it should be `151 - i` since `i` starts with 1

Comment: @VictorMoraes touche sir. Good catch!

Comment: @RobertAltman post this as an answer, since you were the one who first comment here :)

Answer (score 1):

Just need to calculate the sum needed to decrease the increment value, as was being discussed in the comments. Also note the use of `Const` to define constant values , that way when the values change you don't have to go through lines of code adjusting the numeric values.

```
Const MIN_LOOP = 1
Const MAX_LOOP = 10

Dim i, n

For i = MIN_LOOP To MAX_LOOP
  WScript.Echo "HELLO" & i & "INCRESING" & i & ";"
  n = (MAX_LOOP + 1) - i
  WScript.Echo "HELLO" & n & "INCRESING_I" & i & "DECRESING_N" & n & ";"
Next
```

Output:

```
HELLO1INCRESING1;
HELLO10INCRESING_I1DECRESING_N10;
HELLO2INCRESING2;
HELLO9INCRESING_I2DECRESING_N9;
HELLO3INCRESING3;
HELLO8INCRESING_I3DECRESING_N8;
HELLO4INCRESING4;
HELLO7INCRESING_I4DECRESING_N7;
HELLO5INCRESING5;
HELLO6INCRESING_I5DECRESING_N6;
HELLO6INCRESING6;
HELLO5INCRESING_I6DECRESING_N5;
HELLO7INCRESING7;
HELLO4INCRESING_I7DECRESING_N4;
HELLO8INCRESING8;
HELLO3INCRESING_I8DECRESING_N3;
HELLO9INCRESING9;
HELLO2INCRESING_I9DECRESING_N2;
HELLO10INCRESING10;
HELLO1INCRESING_I10DECRESING_N1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just using i, use 151 - i in the second TL1()

```
Const MIN_LOOP = 1
Const MAX_LOOP = 10

Dim i, n

For i = MIN_LOOP To MAX_LOOP
    WScript.Echo "HELLO" & i & "INCRESING" & i & ";"
    n = (MAX_LOOP + 1) - i
    WScript.Echo "HELLO" & n & "INCRESING_I" & 151 - i & "DECRESING_N" & n & ";"
Next
```